# apple-app-site-association file doesnt work with latest changes

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate, aasa

```
Earlier AASA file was 
{
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "APPID.BUNDLEID",
        ]
    },
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
                "appID": "APPID.BUNDLEID",
                "paths": ["/join/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}

It was working fine. Later URL change came and now we have /j/ instead of /join/. We changed AASA file to, 

{
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "APPID.BUNDLEID",
        ]
    },
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
                "appID": "APPID.BUNDLEID",
                "paths": ["/j/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Issue is deep linking works with /join/ path only and not with the new path /j/.
```

Associate domain has value as *.domain.co . We deleted the app from the device and installed it again. Restarted the device, but still deep link works with old URL only. If AASA is taken from cache then how to clear it?

Answer (score 0):

When Dev App was installed from the app center, it picked up a newly changed apple-app-site-association file. Which fixed the issue.